# apktool not found

Tags: apktool

I have an error when trying to decompile apk. In the folder on the C:\ drive there is apktool.bat, apktool.jar and my apk. jdk is also installed, but when I try to start apktool d name.apk I get an error, what can it be connected with?

```
apktool: The name "apktool" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or program being executed. Check out
the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correctness of the path, and then try again.
line: 1 character: 1
+ apktool d Dead.apk
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (apktool: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
```